# Траектория полета объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

**Задача:** Отрисовать будущую траекторию полета выпущенной пули с учетом отскока пули от препятствий. Т.е. есть персонаж. Персонаж собирается выстрелить. И когда персонаж берет в руки оружие и начинает целится - от оружия выходит луч который показывает будущую траекторию полета пули, при этом, если пуля рикошетит от препятствий - то и луч отражается от них, показывая траекторию пули и после рикошета.

Comment: Математика, Physics Ray Casting и LineRenderer.

Comment: Спасибо, RioBr3aker. Правильно ли я понимаю я понимаю - из математики требуется тригонометрия и вектора?

Comment: Да вам и просто векторов хватит, самое нетривиальное здесь - отражение вектора

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вся суть вопроса заключается в отражении вектора, а именно, в получении нормали. Что это уже реализовано, спасибо встроенному физическому движку.

Первое, что нужно получить - работающий рейкаст и нормаль:

```
void DrawCurrentTrajectory() {
    Vector2 position = transform.position;
    Vector2 direction = firePosition.position - transform.position;

    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(position, direction, maximumRayCastDistance);
    Debug.DrawLine(position, position + direction * maximumRayCastDistance, Color.red);

    if (hit) {
        Debug.DrawLine(position, hit.point, Color.green);
        Debug.DrawLine(hit.point, hit.point + hit.normal * 0.25f, Color.magenta);

        position = hit.point + hit.normal * 0.00001f;
    }
}
```

Получаем все необходимые нам компоненты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- **Зеленый** - траектория полета
- **Фиолетовый** - нормаль
- **Красный** - путь луча без препятствия

---

Далее, отражаем луч от нормали через **[Vector2.Reflect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Reflect.html)** и помещаем все это дело в цикл:

```
void DrawCurrentTrajectory() {
    Vector2 position = transform.position;
    Vector2 direction = firePosition.position - transform.position;

    for(int i = 0; i <= maximumReflectionCount; ++i) {            
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(position, direction, maximumRayCastDistance);

        if (hit) {
            Debug.DrawLine(position, hit.point, Color.green);
            Debug.DrawLine(hit.point, hit.point + hit.normal * 0.25f, Color.magenta);

            position = hit.point + hit.normal * 0.00001f;
            direction = Vector2.Reflect(direction, hit.normal);
        }
    }
}
```

И получаем уже похожий на правду результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Код выше рисует траекторию только в редакторе и только в Scene View. Способов отрисовать траекторию в игре, я подозреваю, масса, но остановимся на **[LineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html)**:

```
public class RicochetTrajectory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform firePosition;
    public int maximumReflectionCount = 5;
    public float maximumRayCastDistance = 50f;

    LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    List<Vector3> reflectionPositions = new List<Vector3>();

    private void Awake() {
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer.startWidth = 0.1f;
        lineRenderer.endWidth = 0.1f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        DrawCurrentTrajectory();
    }

    void DrawCurrentTrajectory() {
        reflectionPositions.Clear();

        Vector2 position = transform.position;
        Vector2 direction = firePosition.position - transform.position;

        reflectionPositions.Add(position);

        for(int i = 0; i <= maximumReflectionCount; ++i) {            
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(position, direction, maximumRayCastDistance);
            if (hit) { 
                position = hit.point + hit.normal * 0.00001f;
                direction = Vector2.Reflect(direction, hit.normal);

                reflectionPositions.Add(position);
            }
        }

        lineRenderer.positionCount = reflectionPositions.Count;
        lineRenderer.SetPositions(reflectionPositions.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Получаем результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Количество отражений можно изменять хоть до бесконечности, но все упирается в производительность машины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### P.S.

Зачем нужно сдвигать точку отражения по нормали к поверхности?

```
position = hit.point + hit.normal * 0.00001f;
```

Если ее не сдвинуть, рейкаст может задеть этот же коллайдер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### P.P.S

Непосредственно формула отражения вектора относительно нормали:

```
Vector2 ReflectVector(Vector2 vec, Vector2 normal) {
    return vec - 2 * Vector2.Dot(vec, normal) * normal;
}
```

Данная формула подходит для вектора любой размерности.

Comment: прикольно, только я почему то представил вид сбоку и баллистические траектории как в worms или angry birds

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ну такой подход можно применить и на вид сбоку, а траектория типа Angry Birds реализуется довольно просто на текущем решении - весь вопрос только в просчете конечной точки :)

Comment: спору нет, и добавьте формулу отраженного угла в ответ :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, а зачем, ведь есть удобный Vector2.Reflect().

Comment: в шейдере нет ;) ну и так, для общего развития

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, спасибо за такой развернутый и подробный ответ!